# How to get daily cost report in one call with Adwords Api

Tags: google-api, report, google-ads-api, awql

I am developing a web app usign with Adwords Api. But I am in trouble with getting daily report only one call.

I am using AWQL;

If I run this query:

```
SELECT CampaignName, Clicks, Impressions, Cost FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING 20170301,20170308
```

I am getting this response:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<report>
    <report-name name="CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT"/>
    <date-range date="Mar 1, 2017-Mar 8, 2017"/>
    <table>
        <columns>
            <column name="campaign" display="Campaign"/>
            <column name="clicks" display="Clicks"/>
            <column name="impressions" display="Impressions"/>
            <column name="cost" display="Cost"/>
        </columns>
        <row campaign="test Kampanya: 1" clicks="0" impressions="0" cost="0"/>
    </table>
</report>
```

But I want to get report daily sperated. So If I run another query with add "DATE" parameter.

```
SELECT CampaignName, Clicks, Impressions, Cost, DATE FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING 20170301,20170308
```

Adwords api take to me following response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<report>
    <report-name name="CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT"/>
    <date-range date="Mar 1, 2017-Mar 8, 2017"/>
    <table>
        <columns>
            <column name="campaign" display="Campaign"/>
            <column name="clicks" display="Clicks"/>
            <column name="impressions" display="Impressions"/>
            <column name="cost" display="Cost"/>
            <column name="day" display="Day"/>
        </columns>
    </table>
</report>
```

Please help!

How can I get CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT and ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT daily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second example is the correct call to get all campaigns' metrics segmented on a daily basis. However take note that the field is called *Date* and not *DATE*.

As to why you don't see anything in the response, this is because none of the resulting rows of your query have an impression count that is non-zero. By default, these rows are not being returned. You can use the [`includeZeroImpressions`](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/zeroimpression-structure-reports#including_zero_impressions) HTTP header if you want to also have those data returned.

About the `ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT`, I'm not sure what additional information you'd like to retrieve. If your looking for daily spend over the whole account, just add the *Date* field to your report defintion exactly as you did for the `CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT`.

Comment: Date or DATE it does not matter. I was working with adwords test manager account While I get basic api access for my actual account. So problem was account has not any campaign data. When I starting with actual manager account, reports getting correctly. Thanks.